# multiple-level menu

Tags: multi-selection

I have an app where I need a multiple level menu.

Think of this problem:

- I have 5 bags (orange, blue, pink, red and green) in car 1
- I want to copy more than one to car 2 and 3.

What do you think of this kind of menu?

First, the user selects the bags after that is possible to copy to multiple cars…

[image]

EDIT:
My bags are tabs, where I manage products.
I want a way of copying without needing new enviroment, a new click...
I tried this, but I want something more immediate.

[image]

Comment: Is this even considered a menu? A menu is a navigational component while this is a semi complex interaction for editing attributes to other attributes.

Comment: If I where a user with no experience in complex menu's/computers I would need a tutorial for this "form" / "menu". This is too complex

Answer (score 2):

This is an option too, use this for every car you have. You could change the width of the input venster too.

[image]

When you click on it:

[image]

[Use this live](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags) (just for how it looks).